internal error when listing enrollment tokens
when i was trying to list the enrollment tokens in my enterprise i started getting this error. I searched through the internet and asked to gemini which said that it is a error from the google side and it work work in sometime. But all the other requests work like creating a enrollment token, listing the available devices and all other. so i waited for a day and the error is still occuring with the result as below.
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}

Have someone faced this issue?. is there a fix available from my side or google has to fix it?
Thank you!

I tried to test it using the enterprise.enrollmentToken.list, but I couldn't reproduce this on my end. I would suggest checking that you are passing the query parameters in the correct format (integer for pageSize, string for pageToken), or try to query without any parameters. If you are still getting an error and you are a member of the Android Enterprise EMM community you can report this issue to AE Support with an API request and response, along with the timestamp when this issue occurs.
